# how to detect gestures in a livecard

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, aero-glass

I'm writing a glass app, using High Frequency Rendering live cards.

I launch the live card from a service and I draw directly using the DirectRenderingCallback
This LiveCard have associated one activity related with the menu.

All work's fine, but i have problems detecting gestures. The GestureDetector can be fired from a View or from an activity, but I don't have any .main activity and I don't have any view because I'm drawing directly.

Any suggestion about how can I detect the gestures having the LiveCard on top?

Answer (score 3):

I do believe they did this on purpose. Since the Live Card is within the timeline, they do not wish for the card to be able to receive the gestures. If you were able to, you could cause the timeline to behave in rather strange ways.

If you wish to detect gestures, start an activity in the beginning or have an item in your live card's menu that starts the activity.

Comment: Thank's for your response Jessie, but if I Start an activity in the beginning or using one menu item this activity works independently of the livecard. The livecard (in this case) is related with the service not with the activity. The Goal of this program is to detect gestures at the same time that I'm drawing the livecard.

Comment: It's not possible due to the fact that the activity is the timeline and the gestures go to selecting cards, moving through the timeline, etc. There's no way to get those gestures since it would likely break interactions that the users are used to. I'd love you to accept my answer since this is the route you chose.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found one way to solve my problem, I can't find the way to fire a gesture from a livecard but i solved my problem launching an Immersion activity. Like Jessie suggestion